# Is it possible to pre-populate a password field on a website through a click-through in an email?

Tags: php, html, email, password-protection, auto-populate

I'm working on building an email for a client. They want the email to drive to their landing page which is gated.

Is it possible to click a URL in an email and have it auto-generate the Username and Password for the website?

The website only has one login so it would be the same for all recipients of the email.

Thanks,

Comment: It depends. Is it possible that someone who doesn't know the password could get the URL? And surely you aren't storing the unencrypted password in your database...

Comment: This is a really bad idea. There's no point in having a login if it's possible to bypass it. You can let the browser remember the password, but don't let the website remember the password.

Comment: no. that'd embed the password in the logs of any proxies AND the access log of your server. it's a hideously BAD idea

Comment: Appreciate the feedback from everyone. The website needs to have a password for regulatory purposes but the information is not sensitive at all. I realize from a security perspective the ask makes no sense, but for the ease of use on the email recipient's side, my client wanted to add the password already filled in. They do not have access to the website source code

Comment: not possible without things like greasemonkey installed on the client, or the cooperation of the server hosting the login. there's nothing a simple link can do to "prefill" a form on the target page.

Comment: @ALuci Balancing ease of use with security is tough, but this would be far far too easy to hack. The email would need to be encrypted, the URL would need to be one-time use. The password it fills in would have to be a temporary password, and the users would have to be aware that sharing the link is dangerous. If you have regulations that require a login, either follow it, or don't have the login.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but not sure if it's the most secure thing to do.

If I were to implement, I'd :

1. Create a system to issue a token that ties to the user in the system
   and probably have some sort of expiration and "used" flag to prevent
   sharing of the link.
2. Create a landing page/api endpoint that looks for the token, retrieves the user's credentials and follow through the login workflow for whatever handles authentication.
3. The link in the email would take you directly to the landing page/api endpoint along with the token issued for the user. Once it hits this processing page, check if the token has already been used or not, check for expiration, mark the token as "used", and continue with authentication.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback from everyone. The website needs to have a password for regulatory purposes but the information is not sensitive at all. I realize from a security perspective the ask makes no sense, but for the ease of use on the email recipient's side, my client wanted to add the password already filled in. They do not have access to the website source code.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this (although doing this with passwords is not recommended).

place some code on your landing page that checks the URL when the page loads:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var key = window.location.search; // grab the ?XXX part of the URL
  if (key == '?some_key'){
    populateInputs(); // function to fill user/pass
  }
}
```

And then you can send out a link like this: `www.thesite.com/landingPage.html?some_key`

This is just a barebones example that hopefully gives you an idea of how to accomplish your task.

Comment: Now you've got important login info travelling over a `GET` request. It's very important that `some_key` is a one-time-use token.